# How to make a spinning Cube with 3 fields for x, y, and z rotation speeds?

Tags: java, html, css, animation, rotation

I have some experience in Java, Visual Basic, HTML and CSS
Which language would be the easiest to create an interface with a central spinning cube and with 3 fields which control the x, y and z rotation speeds of the cube?

Thanks for your advice

Comment: This is subjective, and also depends on what you need it for.

Comment: The best language you can use is the one you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `Java3D` if you want, I used it a couple of years ago and I liked it a lot :)

[Here's a site](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1998/jw-12-media.html) with information about Java 3D.

[A nice tutorial....](http://www.java3d.org/tutorial.html)

[A longer, more complete, tutorial....](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:

http://codentronix.com/2011/05/10/html5-experiment-a-rotating-solid-cube/

It uses javascript.

Comment: I am suspect to say this, but this is the best answer since the accepted answer only mentions Java solutions.